# Optimizing a simple query in Spark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have a SQL query that performs `count(*)`, `min()`, `max()`, and `count with a filter based on column type`. As an example, use the following DF.

```
id  val  desc   date
1   10   Test   2023-01-01
2   20   Test1  2023-10-01
3   30          2023-01-02
4   40   Test2  2023-01-01
```

For the described DF I have a script that will generate the following query:

```
SELECT 
COUNT(DISTINCT id) as distinct_id,
COUNT(*) as rows_id,
COUNT(DISTINCT id) as distinct_val,
COUNT(*) as rows_val,
COUNT(DISTINCT desc) as distinct_desc,
COUNT(*) as rows_desc,
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table WHERE TRIM(desc) = '') as missing_desc,
COUNT(DISTINCT date) as distinct_date,
COUNT(*) as rows_date,
COUNT(date) as count_date,
MIN(date) as min_date,
MAX(date) as max_date
FROM table
```

This query is not complex, although, in my prod environment my table has about 1 million rows and 150 columns. My result DF on that case will have at least 350 columns.

When I use `df.explain()` to get the query plan I have the following query plan (abstracted here):

```
HashAggregateKeys...
       Subquery...
          HashAggregate...
            Exchange SinglePartition....
               HashAggregate...
                  Project...
                     Filter...
                        InMemoryTableScan...
                           InMemoryRelation...
                              Project...
                                 FileScan...
        Subquery...
          HashAggregate...
            Exchange SinglePartition....
               HashAggregate...
                  Project...
                     Filter...
                        InMemoryTableScan...
                           InMemoryRelation...
                              Project...
                                 FileScan...
         ... (for each column the query plan repeats)
Exchange SinglePartition...
  HashAggregate...
    HashAggregate...
       Exchange hashpartitioning...
          HashAggregate...
             Expand...
                InMemoryTableScan...
                    InMemoryRelation...
                       Project...
                          FileScan...
```

My cluster has 1 worker (with auto scaling up to 20 workers - It always start with 1 worker and on the middle of the execution it scales up). Although, the performance of the SQL query is not ok. It's taking approximately 10 minutes to extract the metrics (on my prod DF). My doubt is:

- Considering the query presented, without changing its structure, is there any way to optimize its execution time with some additional configuration in Spark?
- If it is necessary to change the query, what would be the best way to obtain the metrics for each column?

***NOTE 1***: *I have never optimized a query by observing the query plan, that's why I'm asking this question.*

***NOTE 2***: *I've already tried using df.summary(), however it doesn't bring metrics for date or custom metrics for strings. That's why I built the SQL query.*

Comment: Did you tried performance without subqueries (... TRIM(desc) = '')? Such construction can be replaced with 'case'.

Answer (score 1):

You're repeating some operations that You can use the already computed column, like below:

```
select 
    distinct_id,
    distinct_id as distinct_val,
    rows_id,
    rows_id as  rows_val,
    rows_id as rows_desc,
    rows_id as rows_date,
    count_date,
    min_date,
    max_date,
    distinct_date,
    distinct_desc
from (
    SELECT 
            COUNT(DISTINCT id) as distinct_id,
            COUNT(*) as rows_id,
            COUNT(DISTINCT desc) as distinct_desc,
            (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table WHERE TRIM(desc) = '') as missing_desc, --- this column can calculated separately and then join the main result
            COUNT(DISTINCT date) as distinct_date,
            COUNT(date) as count_date,
            MIN(date) as min_date,
            MAX(date) as max_date
    FROM table
)t
```

I hope help.

Comment: Even in my PROD scenario where I have 47 string columns? What do you mean by use already computed column? Can you give more details about your solution?

Comment: @OdiumPura, If you look at the my query I rewrite it to new query just. 
In outer query I just use same column for multiple time with different aliases.